# Why are the params from the request object in reverse order between personal_sign and eth_sign?

Tags: json-rpc, signature, ethsign

Why are the `params` from the request object in reverse order between `personal_sign` and `eth_sign`?

For example, the `personal_sign` request object has the hex message in `params[0]`:

```
// Request
{
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "personal_sign",
  "params":["0xdeadbeaf","0x9b2055d370f73ec7d8a03e965129118dc8f5bf83"],
}
```

Whereas in `eth_sign`, the hex message in found in `params[1]`:

```
// Request
{
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "eth_sign",
  "params": ["0x9b2055d370f73ec7d8a03e965129118dc8f5bf83", "0xdeadbeaf"],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda a historical development thing:

- `eth_sign` — was implemented first and the goal was to sign messages to prove the account ownership. It has the account address first and the message second. `eth_sign` however as you probably know has been often misused or maliciously used in that it can trick the user to sign a message that results in a transaction that in turn may result in stole funds. e.g. have a read on [eth_sign phishing analysis here](https://slowmist.medium.com/slow-mist-blank-check-eth-sign-phishing-analysis-741115bd0b1f).
- `personal_sign` — to combat the `eth_sign` misuse, `personal_sign` was later introduced. `personal_sign` has a different prefix to ensure the users are aware they are signing a personal message, not a transaction. That's why `personal_sign` has the message first and the address second. `personal_sign` does not result in a transaction and thus cannot be misused in the same way that `eth_sign` can.

You can even go down the rabbit hole of [the original thread here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/683) that's still alive today.